# override a css tag in flexslider

Tags: css, magento, flexslider

I am trying to use flexslider on a magento page. the problem is that since I am using a third party theme, their comes a tag in the css

```
.std ul {
    list-style: disc outside none;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}
```

how can I over ride this in my css in magento ?

I tried to do this

```
.flex-direction-nav .std ul{list-style:none;}
```

but no change.

[image]

see the 2 dots coming in the red box. I want to remove them. 
I dont want to remove the `.std ul` tag from the main css cause it will mess up something else for fixing this. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code :

```
.flex-direction-nav {list-style:none !important;}
```

Comment: Did the thing. Thank you. I'll accept this answer in next 2 min. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
.std ul{list-style:none!important;}
```

If you can put an ID on the ul, you can target it by the ID too and it will overwrite that CSS.

Comment: Nope. still the same.

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
.std ul {list-style-type:none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid !important where possible as it can be confusing when you come to update things later and it makes it harder to maintain. Surely something like:

```
.flexslider ul.flex-direction-nav {list-style:none}
```

will work for you?